# Long-running BLE scanning in background only works sometimes

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

*Note:* I have access to both the BLE device and the software, so the solution can involve changing either.

## Problem:

The peripheral is only able to connect and transfer the required data during about 25 - 30% of the attempts.

## Information about the BLE peripheral:

- Using Bluetooth 4.2 and TI BLE Stack 1.5
- Transmitting for 30 seconds with 20ms interval
- Using general advertising
- Followed advertising recommendations on https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1931/_index.html
- Device completely shuts down after the 30 seconds, so it must re-advertise and be re-discovered.

## Information about the BLE central:

- Using iOS CoreBLE
- Followed suggestions for background scanning on https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html

## A few things to note:

- The device completely shuts down after 30 seconds, and so it must be re-discovered.
- During those 30 seconds, it seems that if the connection is not made within the first 3 or 4 seconds, it will never be made. I'm pretty confused why this might be the case. (My best guess is that it has something to do with the way in which the phases line up)

Does anybody have any ideas why we're experiencing this behavior, and how we might fix either the BLE peripheral and/or central to maximize the likelihood of discovery and connection?

UPDATE:

Here are all of the BLE-related pieces of my code, through peripheral discovery:

In my `AppDelegate.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *services;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *characteristics;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CBCentralManager *centralManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheral *peripheral;
```

In my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString: @"A1B0"]];
    self.characteristics = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString: @"0321"]];
  
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
  switch ([central state]) {
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
      NSLog(@"*** This app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy ***");
      break;
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
      NSLog(@"*** Bluetooth on this device is currently powered off ***");
      break;
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
      [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:self.services options:nil];
      break;
    default:
      NSLog(@"*** The state of the BLE Manager is unknown ***");
  }
}

- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
  self.peripheral = peripheral;
  [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
```

And just to be clear, this is working perfectly (every single attempt) in the foreground. It's *only* background scanning that is behaving strangely.

Comment: You shouldn't need to rediscover the peripheral. You can issue a `connect` for the known peripheral identifier.

Comment: @Paulw11 the issue is that even the first right might arrive when the device is in the background, so there's nothing that I can connect to. I'm trying to discover this device, and even that isn't happening.

Comment: So you have never seen this particular peripheral before, in the foreground? Can you show your discovery code?

Comment: @Paulw11 updated - thanks for taking a look

Comment: You should opt in to Bluetooth state restoration to handle the case where the peripheral is discovered when your app is terminated.

Comment: @Paulw11 that's definitely part of the plan. But if I'm able to sometimes receive the readings, then the app hasn't been closed yet, right?

Comment: Hi, 
Add a delegate function in your AppDelegate call for "didfailtoConnect" this function will tell you if the connection was faild and the reason. 
Also make sure if you are connecting to right device. Also diddiscover function calls multiple times so make sure that connect call only sends once.